# Symfony loading fixtures

Tags: symfony

i have this project where i try to load some dummy data during the developpement ,i have two fixtures

this my first fixture

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Categorie;
use AppBundle\Entity\Produit;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
class CatFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $catlib = array('Samrtphones', 'ordinateurs', 'voitures');
        $i = 0;
        $sc = scandir('/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/src/DataFixtures/images/img_cat');
        foreach ($sc as $file) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
                copy('/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/src/DataFixtures/images/img_cat' . '/' . $file, '/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/web/uploads/cat_img' . '/' . $file);
                $c = new Categorie();
                $c->setImage($file);
                $c->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua');
                $c->setLibelle($catlib[$i]);
                $c->setSlug($c->getLibelle());
                $manager->persist($c);
                $i = $i + 1;
            }
        }
        $manager->flush();

    }
}
```

this is my second fixture

```
    use AppBundle\Entity\Categorie;
use AppBundle\Entity\Produit;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
class ProdFixtures extends Fixture implements ODependentFixtureInterface {
    private function getPrix(){
        return rand(12.67*10,986.64*10)/10;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $i = 1;
        $j = 1;
        $sp = scandir('/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/src/DataFixtures/images/img_prod');
        foreach ($sp as $file) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
                copy('/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/src/DataFixtures/images/img_prod' . '/' . $file, '/home/moxched/Bureau/e-commerce/web/uploads/prod_img' . '/' . $file);
                $p = new Produit();
                $p->setLibelle(str_replace('.jpg', '', $file));
                $p->setDescCourt('Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc');
                $p->setDescLong('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.');
                $p->setSlug($p->getLibelle());
                $p->setPrix($this->getPrix());
                $p->setImagePrinc($file);
                $p->setImage1($file);
                $p->setImage2($file);
                $p->addCategory($manager->getRepository(Categorie::class)->find($i));
                $manager->persist($p);
                $j = $j + 1;
                if ($j = 6) {
                    $i = $i + 1;
                    $j = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        $manager->flush();
        // TODO: Implement load() method.
    }
    function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            CatFixtures::class,
            );
    }
}
```

when i load my fixtures it purges the database, load my first fixtures then it purges again the database then try to load my second fixtures since the second is dependent on the first it gets stuck i tried with OrderedFixturesInterface and it's method that specify the order and with DependentFixturesInterface and it's method get dependencies it still the same sequence of events that occurring i would like very much to know what my code is missing or what step did i forget any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Hi @moxched, welcome to stackoverflow. In order for us to be able to help you out easier could you please add the **relevant code parts** to your question in **text-form**. This is preferred by stackoverflow as it allows indexing the question for search, copy/pasting it and makes it easier for others to try it out. stackoverflow has syntax highlighting for php, too. Regarding the question itself there seems to be an issue: both images show the same class which was probably not your intention! Please ask a **concrete question** and leave out thankful sentences (*help will be appreciated*)

Comment: What version of symfony/doctrine you are using?

Comment: i'm using symfony 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem the fixture bundle has it's measures when the in the end a request to the database fails such as purging the entire database again without truncating

Answer (score 0):

You can share fixtures between files using References as is shown in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures

In your first file do something like this:

```
$this->addReference('category', $c);
```

and in your other file you can get the reference:

```
$p->addCategory($this->getReference('category'));
```

You have to be careful about ordering the fixture files. The following section in the docs will explain how to ensure the files are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: already tried that still the same sequence of events what bothers me is that it purges the database after loading the first fixtures i verified that with the increment of the id of th first table